# Finding the names of class when c++ code in used as an input

Tags: c#

I want to get the name of all the classes from C++ code (using textbox)

I'm trying something like this:

```
if (text.ToLower().Contains("class")){
    string[] splitText = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
    classindex = Array.FindIndex(splitText, r => r.Contains("class"));
    string className = splitText[classindex + 1];
    MessageBox.Show(className);
}
else{
    MessageBox.Show("class not found");
}
```

I'm only getting the name of first class

Answer (score 0):

I think better use regex engine. This approach is more clear and shorter:

```
// make regex object, to match class names:
// classnames are preceded by keyword 'class' and space chars or tabs,
// and lasts until : or { (between classname and these characters can be arbitrary
// empty space. Or maybe not, so we use \s* where * determines zero or more occurences.)
var classNames = new Regex(@"class\s+(.+?)\s*[:{]?$", RegexOptions.Compiled); 

// Applying regex on the text and get collection of matches
var matches = classNames.Matches(text);

// Iterate through matches and show MessageBox with name of the class
foreach (Match match in matches){
    MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```